# Display Python variables in HTML document via Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, http

Update:
Thank you everybody for listing noteworthy options. I have decided to go the following very basic route using http methods and custom server:

1. make a get request in scripts
2. recieve request via server
3. respond to request via server
4. receive the response in scripts
5. process the response in scripts

I have a tiny project that I have assigned to myself;
it has **three files**:

File one: **main.py**

```
from datetime import date 
<br>
today = date.today()  # variable to store current date 
<br>
print("Current DATE: ", today)
```

File two: **index.html**

```
<br>
//
<br>
(body)
<br>
(div) 8/11/22 *I want my date to dynamically display here* (/div) 
<br>
(script src="scripts.js")(/script)<br>
(/body)
<br>
(/html)
```

File three: **scripts.js**

< currently empty >

I know a bit of the javascript language, but I am having trouble actually implementing it.
**How do I get the javascript to display my python variables or functions** I believe I will use some sort of http method in order to get my javascript to get my python to display on the front end, but I am unsure of "how". Any suggestions? I am using VSCode, and I like to use the LiveServer during eraly stage development and testing, so I am currently using that. But, *I do have a custom python server to tie into this project if necessary to get the javascript to communicate with the python.* **Will this be necessary, or can I make the javascript bridge to the python without a custom server?**

Comment: You need an API endpoint. You can use Flask as a starting point. Then you need to figure out how to make a GET request using Javascript. That's easy too. Then you need to find out how to create/update/add text in DOM using Javascript. // You can also use Jinja2 with Flask to serve Python's data into HTML document.

Comment: use jinja templates

Comment: The key here is that, to make this work, your Python script must GENERATE the HTML page.  You can't just let the server pick up `index.html` on its own.  `index` has to redirect to your script.

Comment: Please make sure to use triple backticks to format your code! :)